# Настройка баннера в 1С Битрикс

Tags: php, битрикс

Я ещё толком не знаком с битриксом, поэтому возможно вопрос будет пустяковым, но нагуглить мне не удалось. На сайте есть столбец из баннеров, его весь мне нужно просто напросто убрать. Я знаю, что есть компонент, и через админку можно эти баннеры отключить, но в стандартном компоненте я их не нашёл. Ищу по проекту html код этих баннеров, но не нахожу ничего толкового, в основном стили. Есть очень плохая идея - просто задать всем этим элементам `display: none`, но я понимаю, насколько это плохо, поэтому решил задать вопрос здесь) Может есть какие-то простые способы найти код или настройки, о которых я не знаю? Ну и если есть возможность, то я буду благодарен в том числе и за литературу на эту тему.
Если это поможет, то когда жму на него выходит: [image: Вот такая настройка]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем это был инфоблок, я уже разобрался. В битриксе есть такое понятие, как инфоблоки. Если появляется такая задача, что нужно исправить какую-либо страницу, но код соответствующего элемента не получается найти среди файлов, а из админки всё что получается узнать - это нечто подобное моему скриншоту, значит скорее всего это и есть инфоблок. В моём случае str - это пространство имён, как его называет битрикс, по факту это просто папка в local/components или local/templates/components, в ней содержатся все компоненты с префиксом str в котором находится этот инфоблок, static.content - это имя инфоблока, а b2b-landing - шаблон. Для правки информации, которая нам нужна, в неймспейсе, который мы видим перед `:` находим либо в файле class.php, либо в файле component.php код компонента. Там в свою очередь можно отследить всю нужную нам информацию. В моём случае мне достаточно было увидеть в коде id инфоблока, по нему в админке я нашёл его и выполнил задачу, удалив ненужный кусок кода.

Comment: Будет здорово, если распишете более подробно ответ -- пока больше похоже на краткий комментарий из которого другие вряд ли поймут, что к чему.